# ionic $cordovaBarcodeScanner camera freezes on iPhone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I implemented the [$cordovaBarcodeScannerSource](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/) to an ionic application like this:

```
    .controller('FoobarController', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, 
$http, $ionicPlatform) {

      $scope.scanQR = function() {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
              alert(imageData.text);
          }, function(error) {
              console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
          });
        });
      };
```

And just call it with this button: `<button ng-click="scanQR()">scan</button>`.

All works, except that the plugin causes freezes sometimes when opening the camera app.

When I click the button, it opens the camera and the image from the camera is frozen. You have to cancel it, re-open it to hope it'll work. And what always works is to switch to front-camera and go back to the back-camera. 
It only occurs sometimes on an iPhone, so it's hard to debug. Is there maybe something extra I need to add in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your button (in some magic reasons) pressed twice. So try the following:

```
.controller('FoobarController', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $http) {
  $scope.currentlyScanning = false;
  $scope.scanQR = function() {
      if(!$scope.currentlyScanning) {
      $scope.currentlyScanning = true;
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.currentlyScanning = false;
            alert(imageData.text);
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.currentlyScanning = false;
            console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
      }
  };
```